# What is the English word for treating someone with excessive care?

Tags: single-word-requests

I once saw this American film where two agents were investigating a crime. Unfortunately I can't recall the name of the film, so I'm not able to go back to the source. The two agents did not want to approach a suspect, or they were being very careful about it to ensure that the suspect would open up to them and not withhold information. It might have been a witness, I'm not sure. The two were upset over why they had to be so gentle with this person. They used a specific word for this behavior that I haven't heard before.

It was something along the line **"why are we *ing this person"?** As to say, why are we taking such measures not to upset this person.

What word could you possibly use in this sense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't seen the film but the word that immediately sprang to mind was

'Why are we **mollycoddling** this person?'

> mollycoddle verb
>   : to treat (someone) with more kindness and attention than is appropriate : to >treat (someone) too nicely or gently

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mollycoddle

Comment: Also _coddle_..

Comment: Indulge-give free rein to

Comment: I just had a Eureka moment so to speak. From the deepe archives of my memory, I somehow managed to recollect the word **petting**. "Why are we petting this person?" Petting a person, like an animal. Would that be appropriate? I certainly think so, assuming the worst about this person. (Innocent until proven guilty, of course. But this was just a work of fiction.) I will sleep on it, and hope to recollect the title of the film. But in a broader, more general sense, I feel that **mollycoddle** is more appropriate. For that reason, I will accept this answer.

Comment: I've never heard of 'petting' used in this sense. 'Mollycoddle' is very good. You could also say 'Why are we pussyfooting around this person?'

Comment: Pussyfooting! Haha! "Why are we pussyfooting this person?" Would that be too inappropriate? In this sense, you could also use **tiptoeing**. "Why are we tiptoeing around this person?"

Comment: I've never heard of "petting" used in this sense, but "stroking" might fit.

Comment: Yet another option, quite similar to _tiptoeing_ is [_walking on eggshells_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/walk+on+eggshells) (around someone).

Comment: @sammyg Pussyfooting..... You have to use it with 'around' ..... It means, of course, 'we are walking as carefully as a cat with very soft paws around this person'.   'Pussyfooting someone' I guess means something quite different....

Answer (score 4):

How about the term "kid-gloving"? Or, as is is more often seen, to "handle with kid gloves".

Comment: For a long time, I thought "kid gloves" were gloves worn by children. Actually, they're gloves made from young goats, also known as "kids".

Comment: Haha! I like "kid-gloving" very much! That's a creative way of saying "handle with kid gloves". Nice one! I have seen this too in American TV shows. (I listen and read subtitles sometimes to learn a new word or two.)

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few words for this. The most often used words are:

1) Pampering

2) Mollycoding

Both mean the same. Although pampering is usually used in a good context, where as mollycoding in a bad one.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean "mollycoddling"?  I never heard of mollycoding.

Comment: @KristinaLopez That's when you treat a fish very nicely ;) Or when someone named Molly writes a computer program.

Comment: It is probably misspell.

Comment: I would opt for **mollycoddling** here. I don't like the word **pampers**; I have a too strong association with Pampers, the brand name for diapers.

Comment: @Samir — On the contrary, pampering is well chosen. Its commercial association with nappies invokes an alternative, but more down-to-earth expression, “arse-wiping”.

Answer (score -1):

Why are we *pussyfooting* around with this person?

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding information about why you believe the word "protecting" answers the question.